# How do I destroy an object in ARCORE scene and deploy another object on the same scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to deploy an object in ARCore Scene and I want to render another object and destroy the previous object. I don't want to create a separate scene and I want it to be happening in the same scene. Does anyone have an idea how to do?

Comment: I do not understand your question exactly. You can create prefabs and instantiate as many objects as you want as long as you anchor them. Then you can destroy them as well. What is it that you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

this probably answers your question: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreateDestroyObjects.html
In Unity there are special procedures of Instantiate and Remove for game objects, so in your script just reference needed game object and instantiate/remove it.

If you instantiate an object with something like:

```
var andyObject = Instantiate(AndyAndroidPrefab, hit.Pose.position, hit.Pose.rotation);
```

Then you'll be able to do the following:

```
Remove(andyObject);
```

Comment: It dooesnt just work like that with destroying the instantiated object. We must remove the anchor point also